# Button to close an individual select does not appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Currently I have developed a select for an application with HTML, Javascript and jQuery that is used with a tablet. To make it more beautiful I have used the property: `data-native-menu = "false"` in order to apply some CSS styles. The main problem I get is that when the list of options is very long as I read in some page instead of being displayed on the same page it appears on a new page.

Normally it should appear a close button next to a title in the header of the select but instead I do not see anything and directly the options are shown, being impossible to close the select. However, I have researched it with the chrome developer tool and I have noticed that the element of the header is together with its close button but on the screen it does not appear as if the options were staying above the header.

I have read the following idea in some pages but even though I have put a label for the select it still does not appear:

> When it has too many options to show on the device's screen, the framework will automatically create a new dialog-style page populated with a standard listview for the options. This allows us to use the native scrolling included in the device for moving through a long list. The text inside the label is used as the title for this page. Be aware of the page and pagecontainer events that will be fired for this generated page.

This is the code I use to create the select where I put the element in the html and then from javascript I load a series of options from a database:

```html
<div id="menu_desplegable" class="ui-content ui-field-contain desplegable" style="padding: 0px !important;">
     <label for="menu_desplegable">l.LABEL_SELECT_MOTIVO:</label>
     <select name="menu_desplegable" id="desplegable_opciones" data-native-menu="false" data-theme="b"></select>
</div>
```

```js
var createListMotivos = function(idDesplegable, selected) {

    var content = "";
    bbdd.read(CONSTANTES.getBBDD("DESPLEGABLE_MOTIVOS"), function(motivo) {
        content += "<option value=" + motivo.value.ZCODIGO + ">" + motivo.value.ZDESCRIPCION + "</option>"; //ID_MOTIVO
    }, function() {        
        $("#" + idDesplegable).empty().append(content);
        $("#" + idDesplegable).selectmenu().selectmenu("refresh");
        if(selected != "" && selected != undefined){
            $("#desplegable_opciones").val(selected).change();
        }   
    });
};
```

If anyone knows why the header of the select does not appear or how to be able to close the window I would appreciate it. I leave a last photo to see how the element is on the screen of the tablet:

[image]
[image]